# A matrix / zero forcing game

Tags: co.combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

Two players, You (Y) and the Enemy (E), play the following game on a real $n\times n$ matrix. First, E selects one element from the first row of the matrix, two elements from its second row, and so on; thus, for instance, all elements of the last row get selected. Next, Y chooses one selected element in each row, trying to choose the $n$ elements so that their sum is equal to $0$. If Y can do this, he wins; otherwise, E wins. What is the set of matrices for which Y wins?

The problem is very easy for $n=2$: the winning matrices are those of the form
$$ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -a & -b \end{pmatrix},
     \quad \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & -a \end{pmatrix},
    \quad \begin{pmatrix} a & a \\ -a & c \end{pmatrix},
    \quad \begin{pmatrix} a & a \\ c & -a \end{pmatrix}. $$
My guess is that the general case should also be not difficult.

A disclaimer: Despite the tag, this problem has nothing to do with olympiads, competitions, recreational math, etc.; it emerged in actual research.

Comment: the matrix structure doesn’t really matter. you just have multisets $M_1,\dots,M_n$ each of cardinality $n$, and $E$ tries to pick some submultisets $M_i’\subset M_i$ of cardinality $i$ so that $0\not \in M_1’+\dots+M_n’$.

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov: got the hint; edited.

Comment: A winning example for $n=3$ has rows $(a,b,c)$, $(-(a+b+c),-(a+b+c),-(a+b+c))$, $(a+b,a+c,b+c)$. A winning example for $n=4$ has rows $(a,b,c,d)$, $(-(a+b+c+d),-(a+b+c+d),-(a+b+c+d),-(a+b+c+d))$, $(3(a+b+c+d),3(a+b+c+d),3(a+b+c+d),3(a+b+c+d))$,$(-(2a+2b+2c+3d),-(2a+2b+3c+2d),-(2a+3b+2c+2d),-(3a+2b+2c+2d))$.

Comment: @BillyJoe: Do you mean that *every* winning matrix (of order $3$ or $4$) has this shape?

Comment: @Seva no, just two arrangements. Just an idea to start.

Comment: Are matrices with null elements allowed?

Comment: @BillyJoe: Yes. I want a description of all winning matrices.